# python: escaping non-ascii characters in XML

Tags: python, xml

I got my test XML file to print using the following source file, but it doesn't handle non-ASCII characters appropriately:

xmltest.py:

```
import xml.sax.xmlreader
import xml.sax.saxutils

def testJunk(file, e2content):
  attr0 = xml.sax.xmlreader.AttributesImpl({})
  x =  xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator(file)
  x.startDocument()
  x.startElement("document", attr0)

  x.startElement("element1", attr0)
  x.characters("bingo")
  x.endElement("element1")

  x.startElement("element2", attr0)
  x.characters(e2content)
  x.endElement("element2")

  x.endElement("document")
  x.endDocument()
```

If I do

```
>>> import xmltest
>>> xmltest.testJunk(open("test.xml","w"), "ascii 001: \001")
```

then I get an xml file with character code 001 in it. I can't figure out how to escape this character. Firefox tells me it's not well formed XML and complains about that character. How can I fix this?

**clarification:** I'm trying to log the output of a function I do not have control over, which outputs non-ASCII characters.

---

**update:** OK, so now I know [characters outside one of the accepted ranges](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets) can't be *encoded* in the form `&#x0001;`. (Or rather, they can be encoded, but that doesn't help any w/r/t XML not being well-formed.) But they can be *escaped* if I define a way of doing so.

(for future reference: W3C has [a useful page](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-controls#further) outside the XML standard itself which says "Control codes should be replaced with appropriate markup" but doesn't really suggest any examples for doing so.)

If I wanted to escape characters outside the accepted range in the following way:

before escaping: (`&#x0001;` represents one character, not the literal 8-character string)

```
 abcd&#x0001;efgh&#x0002;ijkl
```

after escaping:

```
 abcd<u>0001</u>efgh<u>0002</u>ijkl
```

How could I do this in python?

```
def escapeXML(src)
    dest = ??????
    return dest
```

Comment: The only thing comes to mind is to write an inline encoder in `characters` function which checks the range of `ord` and outputs `&#x01;` (and appropriate values for another chars). But it would be slow...

Comment: @khachik: It doesn't work; see my answer.

Comment: @John saw, but still don't understand why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Because it's just an encoding, it's not an escaping, and it's in one of the ranges of characters that XML considers invalid.

Comment: @Jason S: Do you plan to accept an answer any time soon?

Comment: @John: I never plan to accept any answer before I have a chance to look at it, nor do I ever plan to never accept an answer. If you were waiting, I apologize. Stackoverflow competes with many other things in my life (including work, Christmas holidays and a winter snowstorm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"\001"` aka "\x01" is an ASCII control code. It is not however one of the permitted XML characters. The only [ASCII control codes which qualify](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char) are "\t", "\n" and "\r".

Examples:

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
# Raw newline works
>>> t = ET.fromstring("<e>\n</e>")
>>> t.text
'\n'

# Hex escaping of a newline works
>>> t = ET.fromstring("<e>&#xa;</e>")
>>> t.text
'\n'

# Hex escaping of "\x01" doesn't work; it's not a valid XML character
>>> t = ET.fromstring("<e>&#x1;</e>")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 106, in XML
cElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character number: line 1, column 3
```

If you want to include invalid XML characters somehow in an XML document, they must be hidden from the XML parser by an extra level of escaping. The mechanism needs to be documented, published, and understood by readers of your document.

For example, in Microsoft Excel 2007+ XLSX files, Unicode code points which are not valid XML characters are smuggled past the parser by representing them as `_xhhhh_` where `hhhh` is the hex representation of the codepoint. In your example this would be the 7 bytes `_x0001_`. Note that it is necessary to escape any `_` characters in the text that would otherwise be falsely interpreted as introducing an `_xhhhh_` sequence.

This is ugly, painful, inefficient, etc. You may wish to consider other methods. Is use of XML necessary? Would a CSV file (shock, horror!) do a better job in your application?

**Edit** Some notes on the OP's encoding proposal:

A. Although `\r` is a valid XML 1.0 input character, it is subject to [mandatory immediate transmogrification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-line-ends), so you should escape it as well.

B. This scheme assumes/hopes that the `<u>hhhh</u>` cannot be confused with any other markup.

C. I take back what I said above about the Microsoft escaping scheme. It is relatively beautiful, painfree, and efficient. To complete the picture of your scheme for your gentle readers, you should show the code that is required to unescape the nasty bits and glue the pieces back together. Bear in mind that the MS scheme requires somebody to write one escaping function and one unescaping function, whereas your scheme requires different treatment for each tool (SAX, DOM, ElementTree).

D. At the detailed level, the code is a little bit whiffy:

`if (len(g1) > 0):` should be `if g1:`

`if (not foo == None):` has a record THREE deviations from the commonly accepted idiom: (1) the parentheses (2) `not x == y` instead of `x != y` (3) `!= None` instead of `is not None`

Don't use `list` (and names of other built-in objects) as a name for your own variable.

**Edit 2** You want to split up a string using a regex. Why not use [re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split)?

```
splitInvalidXML2 = re.compile(
    ur'([^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\x85\xA0-\xFF\u0100-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFDCF\uFDE0-\uFFFD])'
    ).split

def submitCharacters2(x, string):
    badchar = True
    for fragment in splitInvalidXML2(string):
        badchar = not badchar
        if badchar:
            x.startElement("u", attr0)
            x.characters('%04X' % ord(fragment))
            x.endElement("u")
        elif fragment:
            x.characters(fragment)
```

Comment: "Would a CSV file (shock, horror!) do a better job in your application?" ack! ack! ACK! No. If I had to, I'd use JSON as it still allows structured data. But I'll have to figure out an escaping scheme. I need human readability as well as machine readability so base64 won't fly.

Comment: @Jason S: and for the initial info that those characters were invalid in XML, the point in Edit(A) about needing to escape `\r`, and the whole of Edit2 (much simplified way of splitting your data?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me.

```
r = re.compile(ur'[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\x85\xA0-\xFF' \
  + ur'\u0100-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFDCF\uFDE0-\uFFFD]')
def escapeInvalidXML(string):
  def replacer(m):
    return "<u>"+('%04X' % ord(m.group(0)))+"</u>"
  return re.sub(r,replacer,string)
```

example:

```
>>> s='this is a \x01 test \x0B of something'
>>> escapeInvalidXML(s)
'this is a <u>0001</u> test <u>000B</u> of something'
>>> s2 = u'this is a \x01 test \x0B of \uFDD0'
>>> escapeInvalidXML(s2)
u'this is a <u>0001</u> test <u>000B</u> of <u>FDD0</u>'
```

Character ranges from http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#charsets, and I haven't escaped everything, just the ones below \uFFFF.

---

**Update:** Oops, forgot to adapt to the startElement/characters methods of SAX, & deal properly with multiple lines:

```
import re
import xml.sax.xmlreader
import xml.sax.saxutils

r = re.compile(ur'(.*?)(?:([^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\x85\xA0-\xFF' \
    + ur'\u0100-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFDCF\uFDE0-\uFFFD])|([\n])|$)')
attr0 = xml.sax.xmlreader.AttributesImpl({})
def splitInvalidXML(string):
    list = []
    def replacer(m):
        g1 = m.group(1)
        if (len(g1) > 0):
            list.append(g1)
        g2 = m.group(2)
        if (not g2 == None):
            list.append(ord(g2))
        g3 = m.group(3)
        if (not g3 == None):
            list.append(g3)
        return ""
    re.sub(r,replacer,string)
    return list

def submitCharacters(x, string):
    for fragment in splitInvalidXML(string):
        if (isinstance(fragment,int)):
            x.startElement("u", attr0)
            x.characters('%04X' % fragment)
            x.endElement("u")
        else:
            x.characters(fragment)

def test1(fname):
    with open(fname,'w') as f:
        x = xml.sax.saxutils.XMLGenerator(f)
        x.startDocument()
        x.startElement('document',attr0)
        submitCharacters(x, 'this is a \x01 test\nof the \x02\x0b xml system.')
        x.endElement('document')
        x.endDocument()

test1('test.xml')
```

This produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<document>this is a <u>0001</u> test
of the <u>0002</u><u>000B</u> xml system.</document>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an open python bug for this https://bugs.python.org/issue5166 - not yet sure what the resolution will be/if it will be fixed as it's been open a little while now, but worth checking on that periodically in case we get a proper solution for handling invalid XML characters built into python itself.